# Arranging the letters of INCONVENIENCE so that no C is adjacent to an N

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

As the title indicates, I would like to find the number of ways to arrange the letters of INCONVENIENCE so that no C is adjacent to an N.

This is a problem I just made up, and I am interested in finding the easiest way to solve problems like this.

(I think the answer is 2,187,360; but I'm not sure.)

Comment: And how did you get to $2,187,360$?

Comment: @Arthur I used an approach similar to the answer given below, but I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way (or even correct).

Comment: @MarcusM Sorry - the answer was deleted; but I used the same method as the answer which is now posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bhaskar had it, start with $- V - O - I - E - I - E - E -$.
Either both $C$s go in the same slot, leaving four $N$s in the remaining seven slots, or the $C$s go in different slots, leaving four $N$s in the remaining six.
So $$\frac{7!}{3!2!}\left[8{10\choose4}+{8\choose2}{9\choose4}\right]$$

Comment: This doesn't account for N's together, only for C's together.

Comment: Thanks for this answer -- this is the same method I used.

Comment: Rather, my comment was addressing your description not accounting for the N's.

Comment: @TerraHyde They're counted in the binomial coefficients of $\binom{10}{4}$ and $\binom{9}{4}$: choosing where to place the $4$ $N$'s in the first case is equivalent to choosing a weak $7$-composition of $4$.  There are $\binom{7 + 4 - 1}{7 - 1} = \binom{10}{6} = \binom{10}{4}$ ways to do so.  Similarly for the second case.

Comment: I see that now. My brain must have been out of it for a bit.

Comment: and it is $2187360$